# C++ library to handle eps/pdf

Tags: c++, c, windows, pdf

Do you know if a library exists under Win32 to handle EPS and PDF format files without installing Ghostview/ghostscript. (I'm currently using ImageMagick)

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe take a look at `pslib`, but I'm not sure if it can manipulate existing files.

Comment: What do you mean by handle? View, edit, author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick is available for win32 as well.

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)